# Apache reverse proxy error on firefox : SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm stuck with my Apache config

#### Situation

I have a Node chat web app and a phpmyadmin running on the same debian VPS server. Node runs on :3000 and phpmyadmin on :443.

The server base url on :443 is currently displaying phpmyadmin login page and the chat app can be accessed on IP:3000 (https)
Each have their own SSL cert and https is working without issues on both of them separately

#### Goal

What I'm trying to do is setup an Apache reverse proxy to forward requests from a a clean url (like chat.domain.com) to my Node app while keeping phpmyadmin on it's own dedicated subdomain (vps.domain.com).

like so :

- internet (chat.domain.com on :443) -> reverse proxy -> node app running on :3000
- internet (vps.domain.com on :443) -> reverse proxy -> phpmyadmin

#### Issue

Redirection does not work at all.
Firefox shows an error page with **SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG** (**ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR** on Chrome). As far as I understand it is telling me that I can't redirect to a service running on a different port than :443

I need secure https for both of my services (phpmadmin and chat) but can only run one of them on :443 since one is Apache and the other is Node. They each have their own routing system.

#### What I've considered

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible with Apache and this setup. I'd like to run my main app on :443 but then PMA would have to be moved to another port and. Alternatively I could run several servers for cleaner separation of services. I could also use Docker containers, but I don't think this should be necessary here.
Not sure which solution is the most appropriate. I just wanted to do some basic redirections.

#### Setup config :

Including relevant information about my config in this section.

- Apache version : Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)
- rewrite and proxy mods are enabled
- apachectl configtest -> Syntax OK

vHosts :

default http -> https redirection

```
# 000-default.conf

VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.domain.me
    Redirect / https://localhost:443
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

reverse proxy vhost

```
# reverse_proxy.conf
                                              
<VirtualHost chat.domain.me:443>
    ServerName rproxy.domain.me
    # ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    # chat
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

PMA vhost

```
# phpmyadmin.conf

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.domain.me
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/vps.domain.me/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/vps.domain.me/privkey.pem

    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"

    # Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
        # limit libapache2-mod-php to files and directories necessary by pma
        <IfModule mod_php7.c>
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/:/usr/share/javascript/
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# intermediate configuration
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          # don't know if secret. didn't include. 
SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
SSLSessionTickets       off

SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some possible solutions.

1)Changing the virtual host tag, ie, from `<VirtualHost chat.domain.me:443>` to `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`

2)setting the ports.conf file as follows

```
  Listen 80
  Listen 443 https
```

3. execute `a2ensite default-ssl`
4. Finally let me give you one of example that I have

   ```
      ServerName abc.com        
      ServerAdmin webmaster@abc.com   

                <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
         </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8181/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8181/



            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc.com.error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc.com.access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
   ```